# How to make each pet have a different amount of fleas

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm a bit lost as to how I can have each pet print out a random number of fleas. When I run the program all three pets have the same number of fleas.

```
import random       
class pet :
#how the pets attributes will be displayed
def __init__(animal, type, name, age, flees): 
    self.type = type            
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.flees = flees
    #empty list for adding tricks
    animal.tricks = []
def addFleas(self):
    fleaCount = random.randint(0,10)
    self.flees = fleaCount
def addTrick(self, trick):
    self.tricks.append(trick)       
def petAge(self):
    return self.age         
def printInfo(self):        
    print(f"Pet type : {self.type} \nPet name : {self.name}\nPet age : {self.age}\nPet fleas : {self.fleaCount}")
    print("Tricks :")      
    for i in range(len(self.tricks)):
        print("",self.tricks[i])


# main program


#dog1 information
dog1 = pet("Dog","Max",10, flees)        
dog1.addTrick("Stay and Bark")
dog1.addFleas()
dog1.printInfo()                
#dog2 information
dog2 = pet("Dog","Lily",8)
dog2.addTrick("Play Dead and Fetch")
dog2.printInfo()
#cat1 information
cat1 = pet("Cat","Mittens",11)
cat1.addTrick("Sit and High Five")
cat1.printInfo()
```

Comment: Two things. First, your indentation is messed up. Second, you have just `fleaCount` instead of `animal.fleaCount` (which makes me surprised that your `printInfo()` method works at all).

Comment: Also, just as a stylistic matter, I *highly* recommend that you use `self` rather than `animal`. That won't solve your problem, but it will fit with common Python conventions.

Comment: @jjramsey Class variables like `fleaCount` can also be accessed through `self` (or `animal` in this case).  However if you try to write to a class variable through `self`, then the member variable will shadow the class variable from within that instance.

Comment: Okay I made some changes but now I'm getting issues with the class not being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a number of flees component to your pet object!

For Example, in your **init**:

```
 self.flees = flees
```

Then create a function (just like addTrick) that assigns fleacount to your pet.

```
def addFleas(self):
    fleaCount = random.randint(0,10)
    self.flees = fleaCount
```

and then in main function, call add Flees

```
dog1.addFleas()
dog1.printInfo()
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: While this would work, it's maybe not the best solution.  The `pet` class should probably be responsible for initializing its own `fleaCount`.  OP's problem is that he is assigning to a class variable instead of an instance variable for `fleaCount`.

Comment: You're right. Edited my answer so that the pet class can initialize its own fleaCount

Comment: I made some changes to my code but now I'm getting a name error with fleacount.

Comment: try addFleas(self)

Comment: Okay I added the self  in addFleas but now it's saying flees is not defined.

Comment: Now with the changes, I made the program is getting an error that pet is not defined.

Comment: it's your indentation. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments

Comment: Where exactly did I make a mistake? I'm just so confused because I had the program working and now it won't output anything?

Comment: Okay so I fixed the pet class issue but now it's saying name fleaCount is not defined.